# Can people login to my Wordpress.com website without having a Wordpress account themselves?

Tags: wordpress, lms

I am trying to set up a login system on my new WordPress website(i am very new to WordPress) and have tried various things that did work. However, I came to figure out that when people tried logging in to my website they apparently had to have a WordPress account as well.
The purpose of my website is for selling courses(with the LearnDash LMS), so I don't want to just attract a crowd that already has a WordPress account.

How I set my login/register up:
I went to my settings then to general and checked the "anyone can register checkbox", as a tutorial said. I assumed this would enable a login/register system that had nothing to do with being a WordPress member, but I had to choose when checking the box the default member setting for people registering, so I chose subscriber.
I went ahead and tested the login/register system only to find out that after I logged into my customized login page it would take me to the WordPress login page as well.
So basically my problem is the following:
People signing up for my website apparently have to be a WordPress member already, and I want a website that people can register on and log into without actually having to be a WordPress member but instead be merely a member of my website.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Having a Wordpress account and having an account on your website are 2 things that are completely unrelated. I don't really understand how that could happen, did you subscribe to something on the actual Wordpress website? Are you using some kind of free plan over there?

Comment: Let me give you an example of what is currently going on: Let's assume you go to my website and register. Next, you go to log in, enter your info, and press 'Login'. Assuming you entered the correct password and username you would expect to be taken to the default login page upon clicking 'Log in'. What is actually does is proceeds to take you to the WordPress login page(the login page that every WordPress website owner has to go through before login into the dashboard). So my question is: why does my website try to push my users through the WordPress login as well as my website's login?

Comment: So I guess another question would be: How do I set up a user-account system on my website?

Comment: Wordpress login and website login are the same, you can however customize it to keep your user experience the same. You can create a custom profile page and a custom login/create/disconect account page... etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks...I will play around with it more and see what I come up with.